# NSOutlineView reloadItem/reloadData not working when replacing an item

Tags: cocoa, nsoutlineview

I have a view-based `NSOutlineView` with a `dataSource/delegate` model instead of binding to a tree controller (I want control over the insert/update animations).

I'm replacing an item in my model and would like to update that specific row in the outline view without having to call `reloadData()`.

I cannot get this to work. Either the item does not update at all or the item's expanded state doesn't update. There seems to be some caching being done inside of NSOutlineView according to [this](https://www.corbinstreehouse.com/blog/2005/09/nsoutlineview-reloading-items-and-the-expansion-state/), but even with these suggestions, I could not get it to work.

What I have:

(1) The outline view represents a folder structure

(2) At first, there is a singe file:

[image: file]

(3) The file is then replaced with a folder item:

```
 // Model update
 let oldFileItem = rootItem.children.first!
 rootItem.children.remove(at: 0)
 rootItem.children.append(Item(title: "Folder", children:[], isExpandable:true))
```

**Expected result:**

[image: expected folder]

**Actual result (reloadItem):**

```
outlineView.reloadItem(oldFileItem) // I kept a reference
```

[image: folder no expansion state]

Icon and title reloaded, but note that the expansion triangle is missing.

I can somewhat understand that reloadItem() might not work in this case, because the old item is not part of the data model anymore. Strangely enough, the item's title and icon update, but not the expansion state.

**Actual result (reloadData(forRowIndexes:columnIndexes:):**

```
outlineView.reloadData(forRowIndexes: IndexSet(integer:0), columnIndexes: IndexSet(integer:0))
```

[image: file]

No effect whatsoever. This is the one that I would have expected to work.

**Actual result (remove/insert):**

```
outlineView.removeItems(at: IndexSet(integer:0), inParent: rootItem, withAnimation: [])
outlineView.insertItems(at: IndexSet(integer:0), inParent: rootItem, withAnimation: [])
```

[image: file]

No effect whatsoever.

The docs say about `removeItems()`: "The method does nothing if parent is not expanded." and isExpanded does indeed return `false` for the root node, although its children are visible. Is this special behavior for items that are direct children of the root node? What am I missing here?

**For reference, my data model:**

```
class Item:NSObject {
    var title:String
    var children:[Item]
    var isExpandable:Bool

    init(title:String, children:[Item], isExpandable:Bool) {
        self.title = title
        self.children = children
        self.isExpandable = isExpandable
    }
}
```

Comment: Are the datasource and delegate methods returning correct values? Is `rootItem` ever returned from a datasource method? The documentation of `insertItems(at:inParent:withAnimation:)` says "parent: The parent for the items, or nil if the parent is the root.".

Comment: You are so right! Indeed, I should have used nil instead of rootItem. With that change, the updates are reflected. Thank you!! Feel free to turn your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference:

It turned out to be an issue with how I used the API. `NSOutlineView.removeItems/insertItems` expect `nil` for the `inParent` parameter for the root item. I was handing in the actual **root item**. Using `nil` instead of the root item solved the problem.